# Read-only ID for web-console on JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: monitoring, jboss, permissions

I would like to create a Read-only ID ( monitoring id) for the web-console on our JBoss 7.1.1 running on RHEL host.
Ive been searching but couldnt find anything.

I need an account that can login and see everything but not be able to make any changes to the web console located on 
http://hostname.com:9990/console/

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in JBoss AS7 -  all users with access to the management interface have all privileges.

In Wildfly 8 which is the successor to AS7, there is new role-based access control to administration interfaces including the web console.

Have a look at these guides:

http://planet.jboss.org/post/role_based_access_control_in_wildfly_8_tech_tip_120

http://wildfly.org/news/2013/11/07/Role-Based-Access-Control-in-WildFly-8/

If you are getting started with Jboss at this point in time, I would recommend upgrading to Wildfly 8 as there are a lot of changes under the hood. JBoss AS7 is basically a 'dead' release, there are no new official releases of the AS7 branch coming.